# thread crashes when at "../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S"

Tags: c++, multithreading

Upon executing a multithreaded c++ code (titled DSDMultiplexer) using g++ compiler on an ubuntu 16.04 OS; the program throws a segmentation fault and aborts.

Upon GDB debug; stepping over after a long long time I get this:

```
(gdb) info thread
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  1    Thread 0x7ffff7fd8740 (LWP 7078) "DSDMultiplexer" 0x00007ffff704624d in read () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
  2    Thread 0x7fffedbaa700 (LWP 7084) "DSDMultiplexer" (Exiting) 0x00007ffff732976d in accept () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
  3    Thread 0x7fffed3a9700 (LWP 7085) "DSDMultiplexer" 0x00007ffff701b30d in nanosleep () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
  4    Thread 0x7fffecba8700 (LWP 7086) "DSDMultiplexer" 0x00007ffff701b30d in nanosleep () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
  5    Thread 0x7fffe7fff700 (LWP 7087) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  6    Thread 0x7fffe77fe700 (LWP 7095) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  7    Thread 0x7fffe6ffd700 (LWP 7096) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  8    Thread 0x7fffe67fc700 (LWP 7107) "DSDMultiplexer" 0x00007ffff7057567 in socket () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
  9    Thread 0x7fffe5ffb700 (LWP 7112) "DSDMultiplexer" __GI___uflow (fp=0x7fffe5ffa860) at genops.c:350
  10   Thread 0x7fffe57fa700 (LWP 7119) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  11   Thread 0x7fffe4ff9700 (LWP 7134) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  12   Thread 0x7fffd3fff700 (LWP 7151) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  13   Thread 0x7fffd37fe700 (LWP 7159) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  14   Thread 0x7fffd2ffd700 (LWP 7175) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  15   Thread 0x7fffd27fc700 (LWP 7190) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
* 16   Thread 0x7fffd1ffb700 (LWP 7205) "DSDMultiplexer" __libc_disable_asynccancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/cancellation.S:90
  17   Thread 0x7fffd17fa700 (LWP 7215) "DSDMultiplexer" 0x00007ffff701b30d in nanosleep () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
  18   Thread 0x7fffd0ff9700 (LWP 7216) "DSDMultiplexer" DSDPSIinsert::RemapPAT (this=this@entry=0x7fffd0fee44f, Cfg=Cfg@entry=0x7fffedf71010, 
    PSIG=PSIG@entry=0x7fffedbab010, m_Adi=m_Adi@entry=0x677560, no_of_ports=no_of_ports@entry=12) at DSDPSIinsert.cpp:33
  19   Thread 0x7fffbffff700 (LWP 7226) "DSDMultiplexer" 0x00007ffff701b30d in nanosleep () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
(gdb) s
91  in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/cancellation.S
(gdb) s
93  in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/cancellation.S
(gdb) s

Thread 2 "DSDMultiplexer" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffedbaa700 (LWP 7084)]
0x0000007b0000007b in ?? ()
(gdb) info thread
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  1    Thread 0x7ffff7fd8740 (LWP 7078) "DSDMultiplexer" 0x00007ffff704624d in read () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
* 2    Thread 0x7fffedbaa700 (LWP 7084) "DSDMultiplexer" (Exiting) 0x0000007b0000007b in ?? ()
  3    Thread 0x7fffed3a9700 (LWP 7085) "DSDMultiplexer" 0x00007ffff701b30d in nanosleep () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
  4    Thread 0x7fffecba8700 (LWP 7086) "DSDMultiplexer" 0x00007ffff701b30d in nanosleep () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
  5    Thread 0x7fffe7fff700 (LWP 7087) "DSDMultiplexer" 0x00007ffff7045bb5 in __GI___xstat (vers=vers@entry=1, 
    name=name@entry=0x7ffff70dd127 "/etc/localtime", buf=buf@entry=0x7fffe7ffea60) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64/xstat.c:35
  6    Thread 0x7fffe77fe700 (LWP 7095) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  7    Thread 0x7fffe6ffd700 (LWP 7096) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  8    Thread 0x7fffe67fc700 (LWP 7107) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  9    Thread 0x7fffe5ffb700 (LWP 7112) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  10   Thread 0x7fffe57fa700 (LWP 7119) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  11   Thread 0x7fffe4ff9700 (LWP 7134) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  12   Thread 0x7fffd3fff700 (LWP 7151) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  13   Thread 0x7fffd37fe700 (LWP 7159) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  14   Thread 0x7fffd2ffd700 (LWP 7175) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  15   Thread 0x7fffd27fc700 (LWP 7190) "DSDMultiplexer" __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
  16   Thread 0x7fffd1ffb700 (LWP 7205) "DSDMultiplexer" __libc_disable_asynccancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/cancellation.S:94
  17   Thread 0x7fffd17fa700 (LWP 7215) "DSDMultiplexer" 0x00007ffff7b63e3e in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
  18   Thread 0x7fffd0ff9700 (LWP 7216) "DSDMultiplexer" DSDPSIinsert::RemapPAT (this=this@entry=0x7fffd0fee44f, Cfg=Cfg@entry=0x7fffedf71010, 
    PSIG=PSIG@entry=0x7fffedbab010, m_Adi=m_Adi@entry=0x677560, no_of_ports=no_of_ports@entry=12) at DSDPSIinsert.cpp:33
  19   Thread 0x7fffbffff700 (LWP 7226) "DSDMultiplexer" 0x00007ffff701b30d in nanosleep () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
(gdb) step
Cannot find bounds of current function
(gdb) 
Cannot find bounds of current function
(gdb) 
Cannot find bounds of current function
(gdb) 
Cannot find bounds of current function
(gdb) 
Cannot find bounds of current function
```

I'm unable to post the entire gdb output; due to charachter limit; but [here's](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Gc3MIu3VUYN03KnNnN47qaCsjFI5UmKpgofGpN9sLW8/edit?usp=sharing/) where you can access it via google drive.

As you will see the Thread with Id 2 generates the segmentation fault.

Also this thread always shows this in the `(gdb)info thread`

```
2    Thread 0x7fffedbaa700 (LWP 7084) "DSDMultiplexer" 0x00007ffff732976d in accept () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
```

The source code is HUGE and I'm unable to reproduce a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example as required by StackExchange.

Has my application code hit a break point - deep within the bowels
of the standard C library (aka glibc)?

Comment: "The source code is huge" doesn't conflict with you producing a mcve. Your current question boils down to: "hey, that asdf broke, fix it"

Comment: I tried and tried until I gave up - extremely frustrated

Comment: We will not, and can not, fix a problem we can't even see